# Power BI - How do I append two columns from two tables into one column with distinct values

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

On Power BI, I have values from two tables.
And I would like to create a new table where has the distinct values list in one column from both tables
For example:

Table1:

```
Column A
-------------
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
```

Table2:

```
Column_B
-------------
ddd
eee
fff
fff
ggg
```

New table

```
Appended_columnA.B
------------------
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
fff
ggg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be done in Power Query unless you also need to load the two source tables in your model.  EG

```
let
    #"Appended Query" = Table.Combine({#"Table1", #"Table2"}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Appended Query")
in
    #"Removed Duplicates"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
New Table = 
DISTINCT(
    UNION(
        SELECTCOLUMNS(Table1, "a", Table1[Column A]),
        SELECTCOLUMNS(Table2, "a", Table2[Column_B])
    )
)
```